# NetBeans Change Scroll Bar Design

Tags: java, scrollbar, jscrollbar

I have a question regarding JScrollPane.

I am making a java app in NetBeans with swing and I am using few Jlists. Two of them, have many items and a scrollbar appears to the right side.
When I edit the app the scrollbar looks the way I want, however when I run the app the design changes. The image in the link below shows what I mean.
How can I use the scrollbar design of netbeans look when I run the app?

[scrollbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO9uh.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a look and feel.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Comment: Thank you for the link! It helped me a lot!

Comment: @Kostas Glad to help.